# Vue js- Hide minus button when the value reaches 0 and unhide plus button in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vuejs2, click

The idea is when the minus button is clicked until 0, I need to hide the minus button and then unhide the plus button to add the value again. What I have tried here I managed to make the minus and plus function. Anyone can help I'm still new in vuejs.

```html
<template>
  <div class="message"># {{ count }}<br>
    <p># {{ count }}</p>
    <button v-on:click.prevent="increment">+</button>
    <button v-on:click.prevent="decrement">-</button>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  data: ()=> {
    return {
      count: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    },
    decrement() {
      if(this.count > 0) {
        this.count-- ;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to hide the `-` when the value is 0:

```
<button v-if="count > 0" v-on:click.prevent="decrement">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-show` directive based on `count` value:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      count: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    },
    decrement() {
      if (this.count > 0) {
        this.count--;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="message">
    <p># {{ count }}</p>
    <button v-show="count >= 0" v-on:click.prevent="increment">+</button>
    <button v-show="count > 0" v-on:click.prevent="decrement">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `v-if`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: ()=> {
    return {
      count: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.count++;
    },
    decrement () {
      if(this.count > 0){
        this.count-- ;
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
      <div class="message"># {{ count }}<br>
        <p># {{ count }}</p>
        <button v-on:click.prevent="increment" >+</button>
        <button v-on:click.prevent="decrement" v-if="count">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-if` will render an element if the statement inside is true. And `v-show` will always render the element but won't show it unless the statement inside is true.

So if you use `v-if="count > 0"` or `v-show="count > 0"` on the minus button like so, you should achieve your goal.

```html
<button v-if="count >= 0" v-on:click.prevent="decrement">-</button>
```

Likewise, if you have a *maximum* value you don't want to exceed, you can use `v-if="count < max_value"` or `v-show="count < max_value"` to hide the *increment* button when the count is maxed out.

Hope this helps :) For more information you can read the docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Conditionals-and-Loops